# Serving Express backend with React frontend on Ubuntu with Nginx server and PM2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ubuntu, nginx

This is my first time trying to serve a react app with Express backend for contact form submission. It works in my local machine, but can't get the form to submit on ubuntu with Nginx server.

The frontend react app works.

I have tried using Nginx as reverse proxy to serve the app with PM2 running server.js.

This is my **folder structure** -

```
> React-project
  > backend
    - server.js
  > public
  > src
    - index.html
```

I have set up PM2 as process manager to run server.js.

This is my **server.js** code with credentials changed -

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send('welcome to my form')
});

app.post('/api/form', (req, res) => {

    let data = req.body
    let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: "email@email.com",
            pass: "password"
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from: data.email,
        to: 'email@email.com',
        subject: `Message from ${data.firstName}`,
        html: `
        <h3>Informations</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: ${data.firstName}</li>
            <li>Lastname: ${data.lastName}</li>
            <li>Email: ${data.email}</li>
        </ul>
    
        <h3>Message</h3>
        <p>${data.message}</p>
        
        `
    }
    smtpTransport.verify(function (error, success) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
        }
    });
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {

        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
        }
        else {
            res.send('Success');
            console.log('success');
        }

    })

    smtpTransport.close();
})



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**Frontend** react code for submitting email in react using Axios -

```
axios.post("/api/form", data)
        .then(res=>{
            this.setState({
                sent: true,

            }, this.resetForm())
        }).catch((err)=> {
            console.log("message not sent " + err);
        });
```

This is my nginx sites-available configuration file -

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name websitename.com www.websitename.com 11.11.111.111;
        
        location /api {
         proxy_pass https://11.11.111.111:5000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location / {
         root /home/username/react-project/build;
         index index.html index.html;
         try_files $uri/ /index.html;

         access_log /var/log/nginx/front.out.log;
         error_log /var/log/nginx/front.err.log;
        } 

        #certbot code block --
}
```

I have to admit I have little knowledge on what the lines on this configuration file means. I looked it from tutorials and stackoverflow questions, and have tried tweaking it.

Comment: what is a problem? proxy pass or static files?

Comment: I think it is the static file. The react app is served without any problem. Problem is getting to serve the server.js

Comment: ok then what http status you get? what is response? how it is looks like? is there any record in nginx access logs?

Comment: In the Nginx log, I am currently getting *worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream* error message. On post I get 500 (internal server error).

Comment: did you mange to fix it i have similar problem